# Change window level(window center) and window width of the Image on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, dicom

I have Dicom files at my server. I convert(compress) the pixeldata to JPEG base64 string and send it to my `WebApplication.WebApplication` displays this string on a canvas.Works perfectly.

I want to perform window level and window width change operations clientside. How can I do this? Is there anyway I can relate brightness and contrast exactly with window level and window width respectively. I only have a JPEG base64 encoded string at **client-side** to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the cornerstone library and use it or borrow ideas from it:

Demo app:
http://chafey.github.io/cornerstoneDemo/

Core library:
https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone

Forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cornerstone-platform

Comment: @Chris...I have a simple jpeg base64 string on canvas.Do you also have the same case in your ImageLoaders??

Comment: The examples have image loaders with 16 bit images embedded in them as base 64 strings.  I don't recommend using base64 strings though as the browser can return binary data efficiently.  Cornerstone renders into canvas

Comment: sorry for late reply...Do you perform the parsing of DICOM files at clientside using js?...If thats the case it cant serve my purpose because I am parsing DCM files on server and only fetching jpeg compressed base64 string client-side..Your views on this??

Comment: Cornerstone is designed to display images in any format via the image loader mechanism: https://github.com/chafey/cornerstone/wiki/ImageLoader

Comment: @ChrisHafey - Hey I am using cornerstone now and trying to understand it, but I don't know which step/function do you apply window leveling? I didn't see imageDataData variable (with pixel value) be changed based on window width/center value?
Also, I want the same brightness/contrast bar to control both image and video, for image, I am going to use cornerstone window level to do that, but for video, I am going to use css filter to do that. Do you know what's the formula to convert window width/center to brightness/contrast (a percentage value)?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun WW/WC does not modify the original pixel data - it is applied during the rendering step - see internal/generateLUT.js for the code that calculates the lookup table applied to the original pixel data to generate the output data with a given WW/WC by the renderer

Comment: @ChrisHafey Thanks. I got it. How about my another question about the relationship/formula for converting brightness/contrast value to window center/width?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun Sorry can't help with the % brightness/contrast issue as that is not a part of cornerstone or medical imaging AFAIK

Comment: @ChrisHafey Hi, I have problem to add a custom tool, which is a little different from the current drawing tool. Can you take a look at my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211414/cornerstone-tools-ask-canvas-to-draw-clear-a-rectangular-with-button-click-no